# Position of image view java fx

Tags: java, javafx, imageview

I am currently trying to get an image view containing an image to move from top of the screen downwards. When it reaches the buttom of the screen i'd like to switch direction going upwards again.

My problem is i can't find the exact spot, where i should make the image view change direction. My screen has a very high resolution and therefore i've set my os, windows, to enlarge all components. I can therefore not use my screen size to calculate how many pixels there are from top to bottom.

Therefore i use following code to get height of screen:

```
Screen screen = Screen.getPrimary();
Rectangle2D bounds = screen.getVisualBounds();
bounds.getHeight();
```

My Imageview is initialized at point (0,0) and i can therefore at any given time get the y-koordinate of my top left corner by using imageview.getY()

Therefore i should move it downwards until the value of imageView.getY() + height the image view equals the height of the screen.

But this solution seems to make my image view switch direction a bit before it reaches the bottom of the screen.

For calculating height of image i use the method imageView.getFitHeight();

I suspect imageView.getFitHeight for delivering the height desired by the imageview before it is actually determined by the underlying anchor pane and therefor i am not sure imageView.getFitHeight() actually delivers the height of the imageView. I can't seem to find any other method in imageView which regards height of the imageView.

I don't know how to make the imageview switch direction exactly at the bottom, can anybody help?

Regards Martin

Comment: Wouldn’t it make sense to use the bounds of the ImageView’s parent?

Comment: In calculating the height of the screen?

Comment: To determine when your image has gone as far as it can go.

Comment: Note that [`ImageView.getY()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html#yProperty) is not the y-coordinate of the `ImageView` in it's parent, it is the y-coordinate in the image coordinates of the part of the image at the top of the `ImageView`: in other words it defines the vertical crop of the image. You should be looking at the `boundsInParent` of the `ImageView`, as @VGR suggests.